# Finding If there is an exact mapping between two columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm a Spark beginner, and I am trying to decide if I can just throw one column away from a dataframe.

Let's say I have this dataframe :

```
   a   b
----------
   g   x
   f   y
   g   x
   f   y
```

I want to know that there is an exact mapping between column 'a' and 'b', and therefore that I could throw one of them.

However, if the dataframe is like that:

```
   a   b
----------
   g   x
   f   x
   g   x
   f   y
```

There is no mapping between the two columns and have therefore to keep the two columns.

Do you have any hint on how to solve this problem ?
Thank you

Comment: Looking at this taxonomy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection,_injection_and_surjection, does the mapping need to be bijective, or can it be surjective-only for it to pass your test?

Comment: yes, dont delete the column.

Comment: @mtoto Re-read the entire question. Case 1) mapping is bijective so column b can be removed. Case 2) the mapping isn't. How to distinguished between these cases? Your sarcasm is both unhelpful and incorrect.

Comment: @Metropolis I would like to know if the mapping is bijective, in order to know if the information is strictly equivalent.

Comment: Can you edit the question to clarify what you are asking? It is receiving votes to close because it is unclear. If you can edit the question to make it more clear that would help.

Answer (score 3):

Say that `df` is the dataframe in question.
Assuming you only want to know if `b` is "redundant":

```
df.select('a).distinct().count() == df.select('a, 'b).distinct().count()
```

If this condition is true, you can "throw out" `b` because there is always a unique `a` that identifies the value.

Answer (score 0):

Simple `dropDuplicates` api should handle your issue

```
val dataframe = Seq(("g","x"),
  ("f","y"),
  ("g","x"),
  ("g","y"),
  ("f","y")).toDF("a", "b")

dataframe.dropDuplicates("a", "b").show(false)
```